# How to add a property to an existing object to satisfy an interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Here's what I would like to do in a nutshell:

```
interface A {
     prop1: string;
}

interface B extends A {
    prop2: string;
}

someImportantFunction(x: A): B {
    var ret: B = x.prop2 = someCalculation(); //Error, but if possible x would now satisfy B

    return ret;
}
```

The english version of my question is: how can I add new properties to an existing object in typescript, with the goal of satisfying a more-derived interface definition? Perhaps this is not possible, or I am missing some obvious approach.

UPDATE:
Also, suppose the list of properties on interface A is long, so boilerplate assignment by mapping properties is laborious and not clean.

I also see something like this would work, but it seems like a hack:

```
someImportantFunction(x: A): B {
    var ret: B = <B>x;
    ret.prop2 = someCalculation();

    return ret;
}
```

Thanks,
Mathias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [*intersection types*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.5) (TS 1.6+), you can have more type safety:

```
// your typical mixin function, like lodash extend or jQuery.extend
// you can use one of those instead of this quick and dirty implementation,
// the main reason for having this function is its type signature
function extend<T1, T2>(source: T1, addition: T2): T1 & T2 {
  let result = <T1 & T2>source;
  for(let key of Object.keys(addition)) {
    result[key] = addition[key];
  }
  return result;
}

interface A {
  prop1: string;
}

interface B extends A {
  prop2: string;
}

function someImportantFunction(x: A): B {
  return extend(x, {
    prop2: someCalculation()
  });
}
```

This way the compiler can determine what properties of type `B` are missing from type `A` and ensure your `extend` call provides them.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
interface A { prop1: string; }
interface B extends A { prop2: string; }

someImportantFunction(x: A): B {
    var ret: B = Object.assign(x, { prop2 : someCalculation()});

    return ret;
}
```

The types come out because of [the typing file](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d92c26db699b1776b5869b123f5f43824d1bf03d/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L286) defines the return values as an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) (`&`):

```
assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
```

Comment: The accepted answer that utilizes intersection types performs this operation in a type-safe manner. The approach you outlined does not guarantee that adding "prop2" to x results in an object that satisfies type B.

Comment: @mathias999us: It does though. `Object.assign` is [defined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d92c26db699b1776b5869b123f5f43824d1bf03d/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L286) as `assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;`, almost identically to the accepted answer.

Comment: @mathias999us updated the answer - you should be able to now =)

Answer (score 0):

It's more a JavaScript-Problem:

```
function someImportantFunction(x: A): B {
    var ret: B = {
        prop1: x.prop1,
        prop2: someCalculation()
    }

    return ret;
}
```

but you could also do:

```
function someImportantFunction(x: A): B {
    var ret: B = <B>x
    x.prop2 = someCalculation()

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I independently verbatim updated my post with your second solution at the same time that you provided it. If it turns out that this is truly the best/only solution (which I'm thinking it is), I will accept your answer.

Comment: @mathias999us I also hope there is a more typesafe solution, but I can't think of one (the first would be the best typesafe solution, but remember the 2nd will return the same object x, not a copy of it, the first will return a copy of it)